# Direct Sum Decomposition of Semisimple Algebra by Schur's Lemma

Tags: representation-theory

In Remark $3.1.2$ of Etingof's Introduction to Representation Theory, it says that a semisimple representation $V$ of an algebra $A$ is isomorphic to $\oplus_X Hom_A(X,V)\otimes X$ running over all irreducible representations $X$ of $A$. Specifically, it says this can be deduced from Schur's lemma. Can someone shed some light as to how exactly Schur's Lemma can be used to prove this direct sum decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't leave out the context when quoting from a book. Not everyone here has the book, and the [arXiv version (arXiv:0901.0827v5)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0827v5) has a different numbering (what you call Remark 3.1.2 -- actually it is Remark 3.1.3 in my version of the book! -- is an unlabelled Remark between Definition 2.1 and Proposition 2.2 in the arXiv version).

Part of the missing context is that the ground field $k$ is algebraically closed throughout the book. Another part is that the alleged isomorphism is given by

$\bigoplus\limits_{X \text{ irrep of } A} \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(X, V\right) \otimes X \to V,$

$g \otimes x \mapsto g\left(x\right)$ for all irreps $X$, all $x \in X$ and $g \in \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(X, V\right)$.

It is easy to see that this is an $A$-module map. Why is this an isomorphism? Since $V$ is semisimple, i.e., a direct sum of irreps, we can WLOG assume that $V$ itself is an irrep (because tensor products and $\operatorname{Hom}_A$'s commute with taking direct sums), and then the direct sum

$\bigoplus\limits_{X \text{ irrep of } A} \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(X, V\right) \otimes X$

has only one nonzero addend, namely the one for $X = V$, and this addend is $\operatorname{Hom}_A\left(V, V\right) \otimes V \cong V$ (since Schur's lemma yields $\operatorname{Hom}_A\left(V, V\right) \cong k$).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! My apologies about the book quoting, I will keep in mind the fact that this book has several different versions in the future.

Comment: @RohilPrasad: No problem, just a thing to keep in mind when posting questions on books.

Comment: I would like to add that the commutativity of Hom and the (possibly infinite) direct sum follows from the fact that $X$ is simple hence cyclic, thus finitely generated. Not completely tautological.